# Accessing the arguments of lobby groups

Tags: literature-search, public-domain

How/where does one get hold of the arguments put forward by lobby groups?

I am currently researching the topic of advertising as it relates to junk food. There are many arguments in favour of regulation/ban in books, papers and websites; however, I am looking for responses to these arguments by the industry. I keep coming across articles claiming that lots of money has been spent lobbying against regulation, but these are almost never referenced. Where should I look for the arguments of lobby groups? This seems like the only place to find the other side of the debate.

This is an area that is quite alien to me so any guidance is appreciated. Also, I'm interested in lobbying in any English-speaking country.

Comment: I absolutely love your question. I think it's fantastic that you want to look beyond academic sources to see what people in industry are actually saying and doing. I think the best academic research is deeply grounded in real-world practice. Best wishes on your search.

Comment: A problem you will have is that some lobby groups say different things in public than in private. Much of lobbying goes on behind closed doors and will be impossible to find. What a lobbyist says to the public and what they say to a legislator might be diametrically opposed - and, in the latter case, expected to be kept secret. So, what you learn from public sources may be biased. Sometimes FOIA requests are needed to learn the truth of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know, but I can point you to who would know: **an academic librarian who specializes in the academic discipline of marketing**. At least, at my university, there are librarians who are assigned to be responsible to various academic departments, and the Marketing Librarian is the one I would go to for such a question. Even if your university doesn't have a librarian specialized on this, try a nearby university that might. They shouldn't have a problem with spending time with someone from the general public.

Based on my past experience consulting librarians, I recommend that you book an appointment and that you send an e-mail that describes what you are looking for in detail, and also what you have already tried that hasn't worked for you. Then the appointment would probably be much more fruitful, since you would give the librarian the time to look up various possibilities. Indeed, quite often librarians have access to special resources that are not public (e.g. not on the university website) that you would only learn about if you ask them directly. And a good librarian (like I have at my university) will ask other colleagues about more resources that might help you.

Librarians are probably the most under-utilized resource for literature searches, and yet they are professionals who specialize on helping people find exactly this kind of question. And in universities, they are deeply knowledgeable in not only academic sources of information, but also practice-oriented sources (they have to support non-scholarly undergraduate and master's student projects, too).

Comment: You know, I never thought of this because I'm from the Google generation. Definitely going to follow up. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, modern librarians are not only super experts on Google, but they are experts on going beyond Google to find what Google doesn't index and what is hard to sift through Google because of the thousands of irrelevant results. In the information age, librarians are premium information specialists.

Answer (score 6):

Lobby groups like having their arguments known. They publish them on their web sites, often as media releases. If you can't find what you want there, call them: lobby group representatives will be happy to explain their positions.

My husband works for a lobby goup/peak body and he quite enjoys talking to students who contact him with questions about his industry.

Comment: I'm learning quite quickly that people outside academia are actually pretty receptive to being contacted.